# Flutter Azure Devops Firebase: error: unknown option '--app'

Tags: android, firebase, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup a pipeline that adds the apk to the app distribution in firebase. I have the following yml:

```
# Flutter build
variables:
  app_token: 1:403...
  firebase_token: 1//dsads...

trigger:
- develop
jobs:
  - job: Android
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: FlutterInstall@0
      inputs:
        channel: 'stable'
        version: 'latest'
    - task: FlutterBuild@0
      inputs:
        target: apk
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        contents: '**/*.apk'
        targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'myartifactname'
        pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'npm install -g firebase-tools'
        workingDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)'
      displayName: 'install firebase tools'

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Upload to firebase app distribution"
      inputs:
        targetType: "inline"
        script: |
          npm i -g firebase-tools
          firebase appdistribution: distribute android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk \
            --app "$(app_token)" \
            --release-notes "From Azure Devops" \
            --groups "testgroup" \
            --token "$(firebase_token)"
```

This is the log:

```
C:\npm\prefix\firebase -> C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ firebase-tools@9.19.0
updated 1 package in 11.855s
ls: cannot access 'D:a1a/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk': No such file or directory
error: unknown option '--app'
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

I don't find that what is wrong and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Mostly code but not sure if you guys need additional informations. Thanks in advance.